# How to make R not consider NA values when using table function in R?

Tags: r

So let's say I have two factor variables:

```
a  <- factor(c(1,2,3,NA))
b  <- factor(c(3,4,5))
```

Them have different length, and I cannot use the table() function. Is there any argument in table function that I can use to not consider the NA value in variable *a*? I tried *useNA = "no"* and turns out it is for entirely different purpose.

Comment: How about `table(na.omit(a), b)`

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do.  Do you want `table(na.omit(a),b)` ... ?

Comment: In addition to the option above, you can also make the length equal and then do the `table` `table(a, 'length<-'(b, max(length(a), length(b))))`  The first method cannot work when the length are not the same after removal of NA.

Comment: Thank you, `table(na.omit(a), b)` works. I am still wondering if the `table` function itself has any arguments that I could set to do this job.